# What type of chimney liner and vent pipe are required for a wood stove?

Tags: vent, pipe, woodstove

I am working to rehabilitate an old chimney for use by a wood stove.  There will be approximately 18 ft from the wall chimney socket (this is probably not the correct name for it) to the chimney top on the roof.  I plan to situate the stove right next to the socket, so not much exposed vent pipe from the stove to it should be needed.

Which kind of pipe should I use for the liner and for between the stove and the chimney socket?  I did this very similar job before but for a radiator boiler and water heater, which both run on gas and for that I used `Type B` vent pipe that is twist and click.  I imagine for wood stove I would need a different type of pipe.

Comment: If this is an existing chimney that was built with flue tile, there are stainless steel flex liners available (single wall) for use within the chimney.

Comment: Why do you think you need a liner? Contrary to the hype I've heard that masonry flues are superior to metal.

Comment: @Rand, they are, provided the chinking is all still good inside the flue. Often, it's cheaper and easier to line than it is to rechink. EDIT: Also, in the case of a single-wall masonry chimney, the flue isn't superior at all.

Comment: I agree @TDHofstetter, 6 or 8" stack is way easy to clean compared to masonry+. Most insurance companies take photos of homes with stoves / fireplaces or the 3 I work with do. If you don't have a permit and put in flex or nothing and the house is damaged by a fire the company won't pay! I know because it has happened to people that purchased stoves from my dad, did it wrong and had house fires then tried to sue for flex failure (we did not carry flex and would not try to clean).

Comment: You need the size specified by the manufacturer for the height of the chimney. You can't just run a modern wood stove in a chimney meant for a fireplace because the existing chimney is too large. The flue gasses will cool and condense before existing and corrode the inside of your chimney, besides giving you a poor draft and possibly not even getting all the flue gas outside.

Answer (score 1):

Check local codes. I suspect triple wall will be needed but may be able to use double wall. Ohio and TN is triple. H-D contractor's desk should be able to tell ya?

Comment: Although I would check local codes I would NEVER use flex, absolutely never even if allowed by local code! I used to clean wood stove stacks except flex duct. All the ridges build cresode way faster and with flex a wire brush can not be used to clean it out without some damage, my dads company had 2 attempted lawsuits because we would not clean flex because of the liability we won them! Many places the big box stores will tell you that flex is legal, go get your permit first and find out! Then use smothe wall pipe in single, double or what is required, most insurance companies track stoves

Comment: I'm not sure I'd trust the folks at a big-box store to know code. Even the guys at the contractor/pro desk